# How can we compare the scores of 2 Facebook friends?

Tags: facebook, leaderboards

We need to show players their friends' scores during play.

In the past, Facebook worked perfectly for this. However, now they have depreciated their Graph API. How can we work around this?

We do not want to use the Google Play Store or Gamecenter for this, as people are hardly connected on these platforms. Also, of course making an ID for our own app is also not going to work for us.

Comment: you will have to create your own scoring system

Comment: Our experience was that people weren't connected via FB that much, either. Quite a bit less than half of our users.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own scoring system, or wait if Facebook comes up with a new one. There is no workaround for this.

Comment: I'm curious, is this still the case, or has anything changed in the past two years, to your knowledge?

Comment: afaik this is still valid